# C++ calling function with new thread, no instance of constructor matches argument list

Tags: c++, multithreading, function, overloading

I'm having some issues calling a function with a new thread. The **error** messages are:

> 2  IntelliSense: no instance of constructor "std::thread::thread" matches the argument list
>               argument types are: (, std::reference_wrapper, CPoint)    c:\Users\Lew\Downloads\Programmers Test(1)\Start\ProgTest95\ProgTest95.cpp  339 23  ProgTest95
>
> Error  1   error C2661: 'std::thread::thread' : no overloaded function takes 3 arguments   c:\users\lew\downloads\programmers test(1)\start\progtest95\progtest95.cpp  339 1   ProgTest95

Here is my code:

```
        thread floodThread(FloodFills, std::ref(m_screenDib), mid); //error here
        FloodFills(&m_screenDib, mid); //this works
```

Here is the function Im trying to call:

```
 void FloodFills(CDIB32* scr, CPoint& mid)
```

I don't understand why the function overloading isn't working when using a new thread.

Comment: `FloodFills` has another overload, or only one?

Comment: It has one other overload

Answer (score 3):

`std::ref` creates just reference-wrapper, in your second example you construct pointer from `m_screenDib`, but in thread version - no.

And since you say, that it has another overload - compiler cannot choose which version of `FloodFills` you want to send to function. So, just help him.

```
auto flFnc = static_cast<void(*)(CDIB32*, CPoint&)>(FloodFills);
thread floodThread(flFnc, &m_screenDib, std::ref(mid));
```

Comment: you can't cast to a function type; you probably meant `static_cast<void(*)(CDIB32*, CPoint&)>(FloodFills)`

Answer (score 1):

[`std::ref`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/ref) is a wrapper for a *reference*, not a pointer. And when you call the function like

```
FloodFills(&m_screenDib, mid);
```

that first argument is passed as a *pointer*. Reference != pointer.

Instead do

```
std::thread floodThread(FloodFills, &m_screenDib, mid);
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, this is what I originally tried to do. Same errors.